# Construct disjoint families from a collection of infinite subsets of naturals

Tags: set-theory

Given any family $\{A_i \in [\omega]^\omega: i\in\omega\}$, is there a $\{B_i :i\in\omega\}$ such that $B_i \subseteq A_i$ and $\forall i\not= j\in \omega,\ B_i\cap B_j =\emptyset  $? $[\omega]^\omega$ is the set of all infinite subsets of $\omega$.

For $A_i$ all cofinite, $A_i\cap \{p_i^n :n\in\omega\}$ is pairwise disjoint, where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime. But generally I can't see an easy counterexample nor a recursive construction.

I forgot the condition that every $ B_i$ is also infinite. Sorry about that!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question looks perfectly clear to me. Hint: Fix an enumeration $\{(a_n,b_n):n\in\omega\}$ of $\omega\times\omega$. Then construct the $B_i$'s, one element at a time, by induction. At step $n$ adjoin one new element to $B_{a_n}$, making sure it's in $A_{a_n}$ and distinct from all previously adjoined elements.

Comment: @andreas-blass I'm sorry I forget the condition that each $B_i$ is also infinite. If now do another similar process i.e. add one element for all previous $B_i$, maybe some $A_i \triangle A_j$ are finite. If there is an a.d. family from the original family then it's done, but I don't know how to do. Or there are some other methods...

Comment: The hint I gave produces infinite ets $B_i$. Specifically, $B_i$ gets a new element at stage $n$ whenever $a_n=i$, and that's infinitely many $n$'s (one for each possible $b_n$).

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Now it's clear to me. Since $A_i$ is infinite there is always such a point. When $n$ is running $a_n$ meets a fixed $i$ infinitely many times. Thank you!